# Scan a number into INT variable until newline

Tags: c, if-statement, newline

We are doing Caesar cipher, where the first ROW is the number of characters, second one is the encrypted message and the third row is a partially right answer.

The Caesar cipher is completed, but I can only scan stuff from console, not from actual files as of now.

Question is, how do I scan a number until an end of line (newline character), AND, in case the row contains something different than actual integers (4a4, a44, 44a, a), print out an error?

Answer (score 0):

Read with `fgets()` and then parse

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  char *endptr;
  long integer_var = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);
  if (buf == endptr) puts("No conversion");
  else {
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++; // consume trailing white-space. 
    if (*endptr) puts("Junk at end");
    else puts("Success");
  }
}
```